# Sequelize create one-to-one and insert data into foreign key field?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create 2 tables with a one-to-one relationship.

- Orders (of which the id is the primary key)
- Expiries (which will refer to an order)

Not all Orders will have an expiry, but all expiries will have an order.

Using DB Browser for SQLite I can see the 2 tables have been created and *look* to be okay. All the data is entered into the Orders table without issue. However when attempting to add data to the Expiry table it is giving me a Foreign Key constraint error that is not very helpful:

```
{
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed] {
    errno: 19,
    code: 'SQLITE_CONSTRAINT',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `SUP_expiries` (`id`,`merchantId`,`expiredDate`,`expiredAmt`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`OrderId`) VALUES (NULL,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);'
  }
}
```

I think it has something to do with me trying to add the Foreign Key values, but I cannot figure it out. I already have all of the Id's in the csv to link Expiries with Orders. Full code is below, any helps is much appreciated!

```
var fs = require('fs')
var csv = require('csv-parser')
var moment = require('moment')
const {
    Sequelize,
    DataTypes,
    FLOAT
} = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'data.db',
    logging: false,
    query: {
        raw: true
    }
})

const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    merchantId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    merchantName: DataTypes.STRING,
    orderAmt: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    orderDate: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    expiryDate: DataTypes.DATEONLY
}, {
    tableName: 'SUP_orders'
})

const Expiry = sequelize.define('Expiry', {
    merchantId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    expiredDate: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    expiredAmt: DataTypes.INTEGER,
}, {
    tableName: 'SUP_expiries'
})

Order.hasOne(Expiry)
Expiry.belongsTo(Order)

function addOrders() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const data = []
        fs.createReadStream('SUP_orders.csv').pipe(csv()).on('data', (row) => {
            let orderDate = moment(row.order_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            data.push({
                id: row.order_id,
                merchantId: row.merchant_id,
                merchantName: row.merchant_name,
                orderAmt: row.order_amount,
                orderDate: orderDate,
                expiryDate: moment(orderDate).add(19, 'days')
            })
        }).on('end', () => {
            Order.bulkCreate(data, {
                validate: true
            })
            resolve()
        })
    })

}

function addExpiries() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.createReadStream('SUP_expiries.csv').pipe(csv()).on('data', (row) => {
            Expiry.create({
                merchantId: row.merchant_id,
                OrderId: row.order_id,
                expiredDate: moment(row.expire_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                expiredAmt: row.expired_sum
            })
        }).on('end', () => {
            resolve()
        })
    })
}

async function main() {
    try {
        await sequelize.sync({force: true})
        await addOrders()
        await addExpiries()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

the relation in above code

```
Order.hasOne(Expiry)
Expiry.belongsTo(Order)
```

For such relation Expiry should a field of `orderid` and set `allowNull` to true.
not order table should have expiry.